# How to write the query for below scenario?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I am facing issue with group by in linq. You can see my code below.

**Concern:** I need to display `status=completed` and `deleted=false` then will get the `IEnumerable` below result .

**Sample Data:**

```
Id appName        role    Type    Status      createdAt
1  application1  role1   false    completed   25/05/2014 12.00.00
2  application1  role1   true     completed   25/05/2014 11.00.00
3  application1  role1   true     completed   25/05/2014 11.00.00
4  application2  role1   true     completed   25/05/2014 11.00.00
5  application2  role1   false    completed   25/05/2014 10.00.00
```

In above `IEnumerable` result I need the output like

**Expected Output:**

```
Id appName        role    Type    Status      createdAt
4  application2  role1   true     completed   25/05/2014 11.00.00
```

I have tried this as below Linq query:

**Code:**

```
var arr = from m in m_Repo.All().AsEnumerable()
          .Where(a => a.Status == Completed && a.ID== 12 && a.IsDeleted == false)
          group m by new { m.Name } into g
          select g.OrderByDescending(gg => gg.UpdatedAt).Take(1)
          .Where(dd => dd.Type == true);
```

But not giving the output. I am getting `IEnumerable<IEnumerable>` result.

Kindly help me how to achieve this?

Comment: what is `deleted = false`? Is that referring to `type` column?

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = from m in m_Repo.All().AsEnumerable()
          .Where(a => a.Status == Completed && a.ID== 12 && a.IsDeleted == false)
          group m by new { m.Name } into g
          select g.OrderByDescending(gg => gg.UpdatedAt).Take(1)
          .Where(dd => dd.Type == true).First();
```

Comment: Getting "Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation."

Comment: @user3675226 this is usually just a debugging problem, but doesn't mean that there's a problem in the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = m_Repo.All().AsEnumerable()
                .Where(a => a.Status == Completed && a.ID== 12 && !a.IsDeleted)
                //No need to group by new if you have only one property to group by
                .GroupBy(m => m.Name)
                .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.UpdateAt))
                //this will give the first group (by name), with highest UpdateAt
                .First()
                //this will return the first element of this group with Type true
                .FirstOrDefault(dd => dd.Type);
```

or

```
var arr = m_Repo.All().AsEnumerable()
                .Where(a => a.Status == Completed && a.ID== 12 && !a.IsDeleted)
                .GroupBy(m => m.Name)
                .OrderByDescending(g => g.Select(x => x.UpdateAt))
                .First()
                .FirstOrDefault(a => a.Type);
```

You may need to do an `OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)`
between `First()` and `FirstOrDefault()` if you want the biggest Id.